# gridview delete happens but gridview doesnt refresh?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I've got a gridview inside an update panel.
In the gridview I have an image button.
The button is used to delete a row.

In the rowCommand event of the grid view I do something like this:

```
 protected void gvLineItems_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

            switch (e.CommandName)
            {
                case "Delete":
                    Label l = null;
                    l = (Label)row.FindControl("lblLineItemID");

                    if(l!=null)
                    {
                        long lID;
                        lID = Convert.ToInt64(l.Text);
                        BL.DeleteLineItem(Convert.ToInt64(hlID.Text), lID);
                        BindGrid(Session["SortExpression"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(rbSortGrid.SelectedValue));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I debug this and I see the row deleted in the database (data is deleted correctly).  But the gridview still shows the "deleted" row even after bind grid.  Bind grid is simple it looks like this:

```
protected void BindGrid(string sortExpression, int sortDirection)
        {
            DataSet ds

            ds = BL.GetLineItemGridData(Convert.ToInt64(hlID.Text), sortExpression, sortDirection);

            gvLineItems.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            gvLineItems.DataBind();
            gvLineItems.Visible = true;
        }
```

The dataset is returning the correct rows (without the deleted row) but when I look at the webpage it still shows the row that was deleted.

## Edit

Someone asked for the HTML of the gridview, here it is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
             <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView GridLines="Horizontal" CellPadding="4" Font-Size="Small" 
                     DataKeyNames="ID" Width="100%" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#e5f1fa" 
                     BackColor="#E8E8E8" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" 
                     HeaderStyle-BackColor="#1367AD" ID="gvLineItems" runat="server" 
                     AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" 
                     onrowcommand="gvLineItems_RowCommand" >
                    <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                       <ItemStyle Width="1px" />
                       <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label Width=".05px" ID="lblLineItemID" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.ID") %>' style="display:none"></asp:Label>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                       <ControlStyle Width="0px" />
                       <HeaderStyle Width="0px" />
                     </asp:TemplateField> 
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                       <HeaderTemplate>
                          <asp:CheckBox ToolTip="Select / Deselect all rows?" ID="HeaderLevelCheckBox" onclick="toggleSelection(this);" runat="server" />
                       </HeaderTemplate>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelector" ToolTip="Select row?" runat="server" onclick="ChangeRowColor(this)" />
                       </ItemTemplate>
                       <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                       <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="ibAddLineItem" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/InsertRow.gif" CommandName="Insert" ToolTip="Insert new line item."/>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>  
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                       <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="ibDeleteLineItem" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/DeleteRow.gif" CommandName="Delete" ToolTip="Delete line item."/>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                          
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item #" SortExpression="LineItemNumber">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblItemNumber" Visible="True" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LineItemNumber") %>' />
                         </ItemTemplate>
                         <ItemStyle Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="LineItemQuantity">
                          <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:TextBox Font-Names="Arial" ToolTip="Enter item quantity." ID="txtLineItemQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LineItemQuantity") %>' /> 
                              </ItemTemplate>
                              <ItemStyle Width="4%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                              <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="4%" />
                     </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="LineItemDescription">
                          <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:TextBox Columns="15" Width="300px" Font-Names="Arial" ToolTip="Enter item description." ID="txtLineItemDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LineItemDescription") %>' /> 
                              </ItemTemplate>
                              <ItemStyle Width="15%" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                              <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                     </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Added By" SortExpression="AddedBy">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAddedBy" Visible="True" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AddedBy") %>' />
                         </ItemTemplate>
                         <ItemStyle Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Added On" SortExpression="AddedOn">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                             <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAddedOn" Visible="True" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AddedOn") %>' />
                         </ItemTemplate>
                         <ItemStyle Width="10%" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                         <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
             </ContentTemplate>
             <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddLineItem" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rbSortGrid" />
             </Triggers>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Can you also add the html of grid including your update panel

Comment: Does that deleted row exist after you get the records after the delete?  namely this line "ds = BL.GetLineItemGridData(Convert.ToInt64(hlID.Text), sortExpression, sortDirection);"  I believe that is what you meant, just clarifying.

Comment: I think triggers is messing up with update can you remove that for a while to ensure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Err I got it I just added this:

```
 protected void gvLineItems_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = null;
            gvLineItems.DataSource = null;
            ds = BL.GetLineItemGridData(Convert.ToInt64(hlID.Text), Session["SortExpression"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(rbSortGrid.SelectedValue));

            gvLineItems.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            gvLineItems.DataBind();
            gvLineItems.Visible = true;
        }
```

And removed the call to `BindGrid` from this:

```
 protected void gvLineItems_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;

            switch (e.CommandName)
            {
                case "Delete":
                    Label l = null;
                    l = (Label)row.FindControl("lblLineItemID");

                    if(l!=null)
                    {
                        long lID;
                        lID = Convert.ToInt64(l.Text);
                        BL.DeleteLineItem(Convert.ToInt64(hlID.Text), lID);
                        //BindGrid(Session["SortExpression"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(rbSortGrid.SelectedValue));
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can bind your GridView in the Page PreRender event which occurs after processing of control events has been completed. You don't need to hook up the datasource and bind the grid in the rowCommand event then.